# Amazon Java SDK with Jersey's REST - Can't auth

Tags: java, rest, amazon-web-services, jersey, authentication

I have this working code:

```
package javaapplication7;

import com.amazonaws.auth.PropertiesCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class JavaApplication7 {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(
                    JavaApplication7.class.getResourceAsStream("/AwsCredentials.properties")));
            System.out.println("OWNER: " + s3.getS3AccountOwner().toString());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JavaApplication7.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

And no problems, I can see the owner written in the console.

In the web services project I have:

***Principal.java***

```
package WSAV.resources;

import WSAV.entities.AWS;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;

@Stateless
@Path("/amazonws")
public class Principal {

    @EJB
    private AWS aws;

    @GET
    @Path("/AWS")
    @Produces({"text/html", "text/plain"})
    public String getTest() {
        return aws.test();
    }
}
```

***AWS.java***

```
package WSAV.entities;

import com.amazonaws.auth.PropertiesCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class AWS {

    public AWS() {
    }

    public String test() {

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(
                    AWS.class.getResourceAsStream("/AwsCredentials.properties")));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AWS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    return "testing";  
    }
}
```

When I deploy and test the Web Service, the web shows:

---

Type:
Exception report

Description:
The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Exception:
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Root Cause:
java.lang.NullPointerException

---

On console:

ADVERTENCIA: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB AWS, method: public java.lang.String WSAV.entities.AWS.test()
ADVERTENCIA: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean

{...}

ADVERTENCIA: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB Principal, method: public java.lang.String WSAV.resources.Principal.getTest()
ADVERTENCIA: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException

{...}

ADVERTENCIA: StandardWrapperValve[ServletAdaptor]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet ServletAdaptor threw exception

---

I'm lost don't know what it could be or what can I do... maybe create this another Java file and execute separately from this project, but I need AWS working in just one project...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Annotated with `@EJB` coulb be only managed classes.
The Exception means that your `AWS` class doesn't meet all EJB-related requrements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your AWS EJB bean which doesn't comply EJB standards.
There is a good article on REST and EJB 3.1 here.
http://netbeans.dzone.com/articles/how-to-combine-rest-and-ejb-31

I used same steps to tweak around your code. Hope it will work for you.

**AWS.java**

```
@Singleton 
public class AWS { 

private AmazonS3 s3Client;

@PostConstruct
public void init() { 

    try { 
        s3Client= new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials( 
                AWS.class.getResourceAsStream("/AwsCredentials.properties"))); 
    } catch (IOException ex) { 
        Logger.getLogger(AWS.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex); 
    }   
} 

public AmazonS3 getS3Client() {
return s3Client;
}

}
```

**Principal.java**

```
@Stateless                       
@Path("/amazonws")                       
public class Principal {                       

@EJB                       
private AWS aws;                       

@GET                       
@Path("/AWS")                       
@Produces({"text/html", "text/plain"})                       
public String getTest() {                       
    AmazonS3 s3=aws.getS3Client();  
    return s3.getS3AccountOwner().toString());                                        
}                       
}
```